# How can I make the ListPreference dialog open in a new screen?

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I'm creating a Settings menu in my app to let users set their notification preferences. Right now I'm using a ListPreference to allow the user to choose between Toasts, Notifications, or nothing at all. Is there a way to make the ListPreference window show in a separate screen, as opposed to a Dialog?